In VSCode is there a way to sync the "find" term across editor groups?
I will have split editor groups on a project and try searching for a term in one.  Then I will go to the other editor group and trigger find next, but that other editor group has it's own saved search term.  It seems like each editor group has its own separate find.
Is there a way to make it so searching for a term in one editor group automatically updates the others with that term for finding?

What is your OS?  If MacOS, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/77504043/836330.

I edited the question post assuming that when you say "split windows", you are talking about editor groups and not separate VS Code instances ("windows" in the desktop-environment sense of the word). If that understanding is incorrect, revert the edit

Not that I know of? There is at least some mechanism for shared history between tabs- apparently editor tabs in the same editor group are supposed to have a shared history, so you can use the up and down arrow keys to navigate between the things you've entered in other tabs in the same editor group. My quick experimentation at the time of this writing found some differences though: Ex. new untitled editors share history with each other, but not other non-untitled editors.
Related issue tickets:

Option for unified Search / Replace Bar #72725
Find/Replace history restricted to single session and file #170591

If you want different behaviour, then raise a feature-request issue ticket.

If anyone reading this ends up raising an issue ticket like I suggested, please either comment here with the link to it, or notify me in it with "@starball5" and a link to this Stack Overflow post so I can update it.
